# AWS S3 Notification 'ObjectCreated' not always received by Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

What I want to achieve: I am receiving emails via AWS SES and store them to AWS S3. Then, the emails are parsed by a AWS Lambda function, the result is stored to a database. Lambda is invoked by S3 on creation of a new object.

Problem: Only a fraction (I would say less than 10%) of the emails is in my database.

---

On S3, I set up an `Event Notification`. It's calling my Lambda function on `ObjectCreated (All)`. From my understanding that means, that for every new object created on S3 (i.e. email stored by SES), the Lambda function is called.

The Lambda function does several things, but at least it does this here:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  Async.mapSeries(event.Records,
    function dealWithOneMail(record, callback) {

    var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(record.s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    console.log('> Working on object ' + srcKey);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I iterate over the array of `Records` in the `event` and at least print the name of the object once. I also do this in the very first line of my Lambda code:

```
console.log('> Lambda function invoked!');
```

---

Judging from my logs, the Lambda function is **not** called every time, but only sometimes. Why do I think that?

I downloaded all new emails from today, these are 1,245 objects. All those emails are also stored on S3. But I only find 85 times `Lambda function invoked` in my CloudWatch logs which have been set up for Lambda automatically.

---

Does anyone have a hint what might be the error or even an idea what I could debug?

Comment: Just to let you guys know: I worked on this with the AWS support, but without any result. We moved away from Lambda for this specific problem.

Comment: did you check if the ones not appearing are getting throttled?

Comment: also have you setup any prefix or suffix match for the S3 key name when the lambda should be invoked - perhaps that doesn't match

Comment: You should have a problem somewhere in your setup, S3 and Lambda should work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a reason for your issue with S3 event notification. But I can't get why do you choose way with S3 events? I had a similar logic in my project. I received emails and had to store them in DB.

I created the rule in **Rule Sets** with next Actions:

1. put an email body to S3
2. read email's body from S3 and store it in DB with Lambda.

[image: Actions list]

**Actions** is ordered list, and I didn't have an issue with reading files from S3 with this approach. Let me be honest, it was the pet project, and it wasn't released in real production. But I tested it from different emails addresses (free and corporate).

PS: Pay attention to `Invocation Type` of Lambda action, if you are going to process email in the next steps.